# Can't figure out how to use SetWindowsHookEx within Dart using ffi

Tags: windows, winapi, dart, ffi

I want to use SetWindowsHookEx to call a function every time a user presses a key

the closest thing to what I'm trying to do is a keylogger

I've been inspiring from these projects [GiacomoLaw/Keylogger](https://github.com/GiacomoLaw/Keylogger/blob/master/windows/klog_main.cpp) and [timsneath/win32/blob/master/example/tetris](https://github.com/timsneath/win32/blob/master/example/tetris/main.dart)

I have little to no experience with winapi or c++ in general and I'm in the process of learning dart

sorry in advance for my messy code, the important filles are `main.dart`, `lib/native_functions/SetWindowsHookEx.dart`, `lib/native_functions/GetModuleHandle.dart`, `lib/native_functions/CallNextHookEx.dart`

here's the [zip file](https://anonfiles.com/xaR6JdEcoa/scheme_zip)

Comment: You should try to ask a more concrete action. You can't just ask "I want this, fix it for me". If you are unexperienced with the winapi, maybe you should first try to make a small windows app that does this so you get used to the api before trying to connect it to dart with ffi. The FFI part makes it even harder for you to understand the api.

Comment: @Rene i fixed it lol, will post fix later this day

Comment: Could you post an answer to end this thread.It will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: i totally forgot about this

Comment: will add full answer later this day, basically you just need the GetMesage loop while(GetMessage(..)),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just added this

```dart
hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, lpfn, hmod, 0);

// more code above ^
// i added this
final MSG msg = MSG.allocate();

while (GetMessage(msg.addressOf, 0, 0, 0) != 0) {
  TranslateMessage(msg.addressOf);
  DispatchMessage(msg.addressOf);
}
```

don't forget to write bindings for `GetMessage`, `TranslateMessage`, `DispatchMessage`